# How to go to next screen in screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I have 10 screens running in detached mode. When I do `screen -r pid` I can see the output from one of them. The man page says `ctrl-a + n` will show me the next screen, but when I do it it says: `No other window.`

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have 10 screens?  Or 10 screen *sessions*?  If you have 10 sessions with one screen/window each, you cannot use `ctrl-a + n` to switch to the next.  That's another part of why I've preferred `tmux` recently, because I can bop between sessions with `ctrl-b + s` and then pick one of my other `tmux` sessions.

Comment: I guess I have 10 sessions then. Can you explain how to start 10 screens that I can later rotate through with `ctrl-a + n`?

Comment: You start `screen` and for each new window/screen you hit `ctrl-a + c`, which *creates* a new window in the same session.

Comment: So there's no way to do it from a command line?

Comment: Here I'll have to punt to someone else.  I was able to figure out what you were hitting in terms of a problem, but I was never more than a basic screen user.  Especially now that I've switched to using `tmux` instead.

Comment: `ctrl-a +n` works __totally__ differently here! When I use `screen` together with `xterm` (my most frequent use), hitting `ctrl-a +n` will *mirror* my input from pane #1 into pane #2! Hence the only way out for me is the clumsy `ctrl-a +tab`.

Answer (score 4):

The key sequence is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> and then let go of those keys and press <kbd>n</kbd>.

I always refer to this cheat sheet, titled: [screen Quick Reference](http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference).

If you're attempting to cycle through the 10 screen sessions as if they're windows they are not, and can not be to my knowledge. A session and a window are 2 completely different things in screen terminology.

Answer (score 2):

You could try running one `screen` session with multiple windows, and configure each window in advance via `~/.screenrc`. Here's a working example :

```
# Automatically running some programs in windows on screen startup.
# The following will open top in the first window, an ssh session to
# monkey in the next window, and then open mutt and tail in windows 8 
# and 9 respectively.

screen top
screen -t monkey ssh monkey
screen -t mail 8 mutt
screen -t daemon 9 tail -f /var/log/daemon.log
```

Stole it from `/etc/screenrc` -- a whole lot of clean, documented examples of `screen` configs there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a shell script like

```
    for s in `screen -ls | grep Detached | grep <regex to your screen names>`; do screen -r $s; done
```

After running this, within the first screen, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, release, then hid <kbd>d</kbd> (for detach).  You will exit the current screen and the bash script take you immediately to the next.

1. Lets assume you have few screens open. Lets also assume you have them categorised as work and data.

   ```
    for i in {10..13}; do screen -S `printf data%02d $i`; done;
    for i in {0..5}; do screen -S `printf work%02d $i`; done;
    ...
   ```
2. Applying `screen -ls`, you should have your screens like this

   ```
    There are screens on:
        81592.data13    (Detached)
        81539.work04    (Detached)
        81527.work02    (Detached)
        81586.data12    (Detached)
        81574.data10    (Detached)
        81533.work03    (Detached)
        81488.work00    (Detached)
        81607.ttys014.Mo    (Attached)
        81545.work05    (Detached)
        81580.data11    (Detached)
        81521.work01    (Detached)
        81515.work00    (Detached)
    12 Sockets in /var/folders/qs/cvlbhpr54fnb96vtx01bs9k00000gn/T/.screen.
   ```
3. Now lets isolate the detached screens using `grep`.

   ```
    screen -ls | grep Detached
   ```

You should get something like this

```
        81592.data13    (Detached)
        81539.work04    (Detached)
        81527.work02    (Detached)
        81586.data12    (Detached)
        81574.data10    (Detached)
        81533.work03    (Detached)
        81488.work00    (Detached)
        81545.work05    (Detached)
        81580.data11    (Detached)
        81521.work01    (Detached)
        81515.work00    (Detached)
```

3. Now lets select the ones you want (e.g. data), again using `grep`.

   ```
    screen -ls | grep Detached | grep data
   ```

This will isolate only the data screens. You can change the grep keyword with regular expressions to search to customise your search.

```
        81592.data13    (Detached)
        81586.data12    (Detached)
        81574.data10    (Detached)
        81580.data11    (Detached)
```

4. Luckily the result is well structured and tab delimited. Now lets split the columns into fields and choose the 2nd field using `cut`.

   ```
    screen -ls | grep Detached | grep data | cut -d'       ' -f2
   ```

You will need to press `ctrl+v` then tab to insert a `tab` after the delimiter parameter `-d`. The results should be like this.

```
81592.data13
81586.data12
81574.data10
81580.data11
```

5. Now pack this into a command using the `...` quotes and loop over the results like this. Always check the formulated commands 1st before actually running it. I used `echo screen -r`

   ```
    for s in `screen -ls | \
    grep Detached | grep data | \
    cut -d'     ' -f2`; do \
        echo screen -r $s; \
    done
   ```
6. If all goes good, then try it without `echo`.

   ```
    for s in `screen -ls | \
    grep Detached | grep data | \
    cut -d'     ' -f2`; do \
        screen -r $s; \
    done
   ```
7. Voila. Each screen you detach from takes you to the next one.

Happy screening!!

Answer (score 0):

These are handy:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> — next window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>backspace</kbd> — previous window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> — windowlist menu
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> — select window 0

(see also `man screen`)